# Using .NET Regex to parse WSUS updates for currently installed packages

Tags: c#, .net, regex, vb.net

**Problem:**
 Current regex pattern does not filter all lines. Adding ^ to the beginning and $ to the ending of the pattern seems to break it as well. If I try it on http://www.regexlib.com it gives partial results using options(multiline & case insensitive). Using it in the application returns nothing at all.

**Questions:**

1. Why is this regex not working with
   all lines and partially giving results.
2. I thought this was .NET regex
   engine. Why does it work there and
   not here???
3. Am I missing proper syntax or is the
   pattern just missing sommething
   crucial?? Regex always drives me crazy...

// Format: (KB980218)
//
// Example:
 Security Update for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems (KB2479943)
Security Update for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems (KB2479943)
Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool x64 - March 2011 (KB890830)
Update for Microsoft Silverlight (KB2495644)
Security Update for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems (KB2483614)
Cumulative Security Update for Internet Explorer 8 for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems (KB2482017)
Security Update for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems (KB2425227)
Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool x64 - February 2011 (KB890830)
Security Update for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems (KB2479628)
Update for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems (KB2467023)
Windows Live Essentials 2011 (KB2434419)
Update for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems (KB2454826)
Security Update for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems (KB2475792)
Security Update for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems (KB2393802)
Security Update for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems (KB2485376)
Update for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems (KB976902)
Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool x64 - January 2011 (KB890830)
Security Update for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems (KB2419640)
Update for Internet Explorer 8 Compatibility View List for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems (KB2447568)
Cumulative Update for Media Center for Windows 7 x64-based Systems (KB2284742)
Update for Microsoft Silverlight (KB2477244)

Testing this function returns the title but no kb article number.

==================================================================================
Title:Security Update for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems (KB2479943)
KB#:
==================================================================================
Title:Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool x64 - March 2011 (KB890830)
KB#:
==================================================================================
Title:Update for Microsoft Silverlight (KB2495644)
KB#:
==================================================================================

```
//Main Method output example
Console.WriteLine("=====================================================================================");
foreach (string s in KbUpdates)
{
    string format = string.Format("Title:{0}\r\nKB#:{1}", s, GrabKBUpdate(s.ToString()));

    Console.WriteLine(format);
    Console.WriteLine("=====================================================================================");
}

public static string GrabKBUpdate(string updatestring)
{
    string result = null;
    string pattern = @"(((\w{2}\d{6}) ?)";
    string input = updatestring;
    Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    MatchCollection matches = rgx.Matches(input);

    if (matches.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (Match match in matches)
           result = match.Value;
        return result;
    }
    return result;

}
```

Using this method above I get nothing. Using the below pattern on http://www.regexlib.com online regex tester for .net I only get partial results.
Matches for pattern: (((\w{2}\d{6}) ?)

```
Match   $1  $2
(KB890830)  (KB890830)  (KB890830)
(KB890830)  (KB890830)  (KB890830)
(KB976902)  (KB976902)  (KB976902)
(KB890830)  (KB890830)  (KB890830)
```

Comment: What are you expecting the regex match in `GrabKBUpdate` to do? It looks to me like it'll match repeated words, but I can't see why you'd want to do that.

Comment: The other pattern you mention at the end seems to be missing (at least) a backslash before the `d`, and to have mismatched parentheses. When you say you "only get partial results", what do you mean? For instance, do you mean that you fed it all the lines that you listed earlier and the only matches you found were the four you listed at the end, or what?

Comment: My bad! I had the wrong pattern in the first case second I just didn't copy pasted from notepad which was not in the project. Its fixed now. on this page.

Comment: To answer your question about GrabKBUpdate(). It is supposed to return the kbarticle from a string. Should look like this (KB890830). Example block is above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up that the pattern needed was (KB\d+). Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

First, note that some of the KB numbers have six digits, and some have seven.  The expression to match the KB number alone can be simply

```
\(KB\d{6,7}\)
```

I think that explains why your code was matching some of the lines but not others.  This also works for me on the regexlib tester with CaseInsensitive and Multiline.  Note that you need to escape the parentheses in the pattern, otherwise they have special meaning (to delimit a capture group).

I hope that answers your questions.  In any case, it looks like you need to examine the logic of your method, since you have

```
foreach (Match match in matches)
    result = match.Value;
return result;
```

which doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Although it doesn't matter any more: the `\1` was a backreference. It means "whatever was matched by the first parenthesized group in this RE". (Strictly, using backreferences means that what you have is no longer a *regular* expression in the original technical sense, but "regular expression" has long meant something more general than that original technical sense.)

Comment: I don't think there's anything awful about the `foreach` loop. S/he just wants to return the last match, if any, and `null` otherwise. It's hardly the most efficient way, but I bet that doesn't matter in practice in this application.

Comment: @Gareth Sorry to make your comment irrelevant by my last edit.  I realized after I posted that a lot of what I said was not really important.  Thanks for the reminder about the backreference.  It's been awhile since I used it.

Comment: No problem. (To our hordes of future readers: Nightforce2's question originally had the wrong regexp in it; Kimberley's answer originally asked a question about that wrong regexp; my comment was addressing Kimberley's answer. Nightforce fixed the wrong regexp and Kimberley removed the question about it :-).)

Comment: Didn't check it fully before posting is all. I forgot I had a totally different function in notepad vs. what was in the IDE and copied the notepad version instead. She does have a good understanding and that is what mine had in mind originally. Just as you can see mine is just a little different. The foreach was aimed at returning the first match not pretty but it would work and you always have the choice to change it later if needed(Which would be would be done just needed to test the regex pattern).